# Error in AndroidManifest.xml file !

Tags: android, android-manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="org.example.sudoku"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".Sudoku"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
  //error here->//      <activity android:name=".about"
        android:label="@string/about_title">


</activity>

    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

</manifest>
```

//Th problem is ,when I was developing a sudoku game I got an error in defining the activity (.about).
Above I have written the code and the place where the error occurred. Please help//

Comment: Could you paste some more of your manifest? And tell us what the error is you're getting? (if you're using eclips: hover over the error/red lines and wait a bit...)

Comment: Ah, it was there, but the layout made it hidden? strange. fixed layout

Comment: Class/Activity name should always start with capital letters its not `.about` it should be `.About`. In general it's not a good practice.

Answer (score 3):

I see nothing strange. Could it be that you where trying for `".About"` instead of `".about`" ?

Answer (score 2):

Some things to check:

- `About` starts with capital letter as Nanne said.
- `About` should be in package `org.example.sudoku`.
- `About` should extend `Activity`.

Also notice that instead of doing:

```
<activity android:name=".About"
        android:label="@string/about_title">
</activity>
```

You can do:

```
<activity android:name=".About"
        android:label="@string/about_title"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
<activity
    android:label="@string/about_title"
    android:name=".About"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
    />
```